# Issue with c++ switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm having an issue with a switch statement in c++.

I have built a menu in which I can select various things to do, when I select a function that does not require any variables to be set i.e. getstat() - calls stats, it works fine. However every time I select a function that takes a variable the code runs perfectly but when it loops back through for the next selection it sticks on what was previously selected.

Any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

On the code below I check my stats (works fine), then select kick the ball, enter the required distance, the function kicks the ball, I then want to select Check distance but when I try to its already selected kick the ball.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the cin as the other functions don't have a cin and they work perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int distance = 0;
int target;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string Menu[3] = { "Check stats", "kick the ball", "Check distance" };
int pointer = 0;

while (true)
{
    system("cls");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
    cout << "Main Menu\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        if (i == pointer)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
            cout << Menu[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
        {
            pointer -= 1;
            if (pointer == -1)
            {
                pointer = 2;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
        {
            pointer += 1;
            if (pointer == 4)
            {
                pointer = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
        {
            switch (pointer)
            {
            case 0:
            {
                cout << "\n\n\nPlaying Check stats";
                cout << me.stats();
                Sleep(1000);
            } break;
            case 1:
            {
                cout << "\n\n\n Kick the ball \n how far?";
                cin >> distance; 
                target = distance;
                me.kick();
                Sleep(1000);
            } break;
            case 2:
            {
                cout << "\n\n\nCheck distance";
                me.distance();
                Sleep(1000);
            } break;

            case 3:
            {
                return 0;
            } break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    Sleep(150);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using **break** in your **if/else if** statements wouldn't that take you out of the loop after the first try? i.e in all case you are going to break out of the loop, so what is its purpose here? In other word what keeps the while loop running?

Comment: I need to use break statements or the selector will not move up or down the options. The only issue I have is when it selects Kick the ball i.e. the cin us utilised, I don't see the break statements casing the issue. The loop will run while (true), I have a separate counter to stop the loop at a certain point.

Comment: So is there another loop outside of the while loop? What is the purpose of this particular **while(true)** loop? What i mean is the for example the moment the user presses the down arrow key the pointer variable is incremented,then a conditional test(pointer+=1;....) then you break out of the loop,then what happens?

Comment: I am having a difficult time reproducing your problem because with your current code, when i press the arrow keys the loop will terminate because there is a break in every **if/else if** statement with in the loop, so i don't see how this loop "will run while(true)". May be you should provide more of your code than given above.

Comment: Added the first part of code which I didn't think would make a difference, @bkVnet please try again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that after you enter a value from the keyboard you have to press enter(VK_RETURN) for cin to read the value, and according to the documentation of GetAsyncKeyState() function at MSDN:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key
>   was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the
>   key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the
>   key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was
>   pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

That means the function call will return true even for the last key press after the previous call to it,so after you press enter to get the input with cin,the next time you come around `else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)` will be true(without pressing any key this time) and ask you to enter the distance...and so on...

You could do something like this though(by all means not the best solution to get what you are trying to accomplish):

```
int flag=1;
while (true) {
system("cls");

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
cout << "Main Menu\n\n";

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    if (i == pointer)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
        cout << Menu[i] << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
        cout << Menu[i] << endl;
    }
}
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
        pointer -= 1;
        if (pointer == -1)
        {
            pointer = 2;
        }
        flag=1;
        //break;//i don't know why you need this one
    }
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0) {
        pointer += 1;
        if (pointer == 7)
        {
            pointer = 0;
        }
        flag=1;
        //break;//i don't know why you need this one
    }
else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0 && flag){
        switch (pointer) {
        case 0: cout << "\n\n\n Call stats!";
            me.stats(); //this works perfectly and I can 
            Sleep(1000) //select a different option on the next loop.
        break;
        case 1: cout << "\n\n\n Kick the ball \n how far in meters?";
            FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
            cin >> choice; //previously defined
            flag=0;//makes the next else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0 && flag) false,otherwise since enter(VK_RETURN) will be pressed to get input using cin,you will enter in an endless loop which leads only to here...
            Sleep(1000);
          break;
        case 2: cout << "\n\n\n Check distance";
            me.distance();
            Sleep(1000);
        break;
        case 3: return 0; //Exit
         break;
        }
        //break;//i don't know why you need this one
        }
        else
           flag=1;
    }
  Sleep(150);

  }
```

Comment: That's helped a lot thanks, unfortunately it's thrown up another issue where if I re-select kick the ball at any point the previous value stored in target is still there and I'm unsure how to reset target to accept a new input.

Comment: @here2learn Adding FlushConsoleInputBuffer(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)); before the call to cin seems to clear the input buffer.